# Cable Size Measurements

Tags: cables, component-selection, conductivity

I need some help in order to  select the right cable for a design that I am working on, given that this cable is a 100 m long, able to handle 5.5 MW and a Voltage of 400 V.

I need a formula or a criteria in order to find the cable size

Comment: I would not consider that a cable anymore...

Comment: Explain please?

Comment: This is not a task for someone who has to ask this question. You will be needing copper bars, not cables. You could consult your local power company about this: they will know who to refer you to for handling currents in excess of 10,000 amps - special consideration may be needed for the magnetic field generated.

Comment: 5.5MW at 400V is roughly 14kA. If you really need to design something that must "handle" 5.5MW and you cannot select a cable for yourself, probably you are not up to the task.

Comment: Is that 5.5MegaWatts? Or do I have some fuzz in my ear? Why don't you start with some copper blocks with a cross section of a few square feet.

Comment: BTW, are you sure you need to handle 4.4MW? Do you realize that an average car engine has a power of the order of tens of kW. So, do you really need to handle the power of hundreds of cars?!? If this is for work, ask for professional advice. If it is for hobby, probably you did some mistake in your back-of-the- envelope calculations. Moreover, if you describe your design in more detail we could be able to give better advice.

Comment: I am aware of the stupidity of the question itself, I am just totally lost to find an answer. This was asked from me as an Intern in Electrical engineering so yes I am not so good in this yet.

Comment: @MN93 Maybe the question was asked of you to find out if you know that sometimes the best answer is to say that you will have to find out who you should consult. You are not expected to know all the answers. You *are* expected to know that you do not know all the answers.

Comment: I considered this too, but no an answer was demanded instead :)

Comment: The question is not stupid. It depend on the context. Now that you have clarified the context it is understandable that maybe it was some sort of trick question to probe your understanding. Or did they really hand you the actual design problem?

Comment: @MN93 You do not know the answer. Stand your ground. Lives may depend on getting this correct.

Comment: @MN93 Is it AC or DC?

Comment: its an AC earth cable as far as i know, and yes i do agree with you @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 1):

First, start by determining the power dissipation limit in each conductor. Since power is current squared times resistance, and you know the current from the power and voltage, you can determine the resistance of the conductor. Since you know the resistivity of copper (or you can at least look it up), and resistance equals resistivity time area times length, you can calculate the cross-sectional area of the conductors.

Comment: This was the last result that i have found after searching the web, there is this formula which i belive you are talking about it:           Wire Circular mils =2 x ρ x I x L / (%Allowable Voltage drop of source voltage)

Comment: It's a ridiculous amount of power at that voltage. For example, if you are using copper, and could afford to waste 1% of the power in the conductors (i.e., 55 kW), you would still need bus bars with about a 4-inch square cross-section. This is why @PlasmaHH would not call it a "cable".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think its clear now that this was a tricky question for me as an Intern.

Comment: @MN93 - "this formula which i belive you are talking about it" Nope. Or at least not directly. If you know the current (and you do), then you can use it if you know the acceptable voltage drop for the wire, since voltage times current will give you power. How much power are you willing to dissipate in your  "cable"?

Comment: yes, true the current can be calculated, I assume 5% Voltage drop is acceptable and then its should be just simple math. this link has the calculation method: http://www.adamselectric.coop/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Voltage-Drop.pdf

Comment: @MN93 - " I assume 5% Voltage drop is acceptable" Holy Mother of God, no! A 5% voltage drop means 5% of the power is dissipated in the cable. 5% of 5.5 MW is how much? Pay attention to the power! That's why I set up my answer as I did.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast megawatt? [What the ... is a megawatt?!?](https://media.giphy.com/media/ITUJNUnX25T7q/giphy.gif). Sorry, I couldn't resist!!! :-)

Comment: @MN93 - And I notice that, although you selected my answer, you didn't actually do as I recommended. Instead, you went and found a formula on the internet whose implications you did not understand. I grant that you are an intern, and in over your head, but you need to start thinking for yourself. Go to my answer, and do the bloody math. Just as an example, if you allow 5% drop, you'll dissipate 275 kW in your cable, and that's 2.75 kW per meter of cable, or (since I'm American) about a kilowatt per foot. Does that sound remotely reasonable? If so, go talk to your supervisor.

Comment: Watch your language first of all, I know the question was asked in a very bad way, lacking a lot of information. the idea is as an Intern which is nothing to be ashamed of, I was just trying to make sure that I am looking in the right place. Today i completed the whole calculation and what surprised myself is that the Cable cannot be created in Real life due to its enormous size, I had to find the Area of the conductor and then divide it to the biggest diameter of a cable that can be manufactured in order to put 100+cables in an arrangement that serves the same purpose of that imaginary one.

Comment: I just want to say thanks for anyone who gave me a hint of an info. and also thanks for the people who were making jokes and nonsense about the question ( Totally fair as i said above the question was asked in a wrong way). This was my first question here and probably my last :)

Comment: @MN93 - As to cable size, you should be aware that, for very high power installations, cables don't necessarily need to be flexible or easily connected or disconnected. After all, a 5.5 MW power plant is not easily moved. Generating stations commonly use buss bars as the primary current conductor.

Comment: I agree with you. i suggested to do so also "Add Bus bars" but the customer doesn't need this solution. As you know sometimes money talks and engineers must just do.